# Backing Up mmssms.db From /data/ With Root Permissions

Tags: android

I am trying to write an Android application for myself that will simply copy the file located at /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db to a location on my sdcard, /sdcard/test/mmssms.db

The device is rooted and the application has been granted super user access but the file is never actually copied. The destination directory does exist and the SDK for the application for is 1.5. The following are the commands used to perform the backup.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases /data");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db /sdcard/test/mmssms.db");
```

The following permission is used in the Manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I would just like to know what I can do to be able to copy the that file and the others in the /data/ directory. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, I can't seem to get this to work in an app. A few helpful notes about your code snippet though:

- Running these commands as separate calls to Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is pointless, because each invokation of exec starts a new child process with the same priveledges as your app. Running exec("su") does not give root permissions to the commands following (mount, chmod etc) because they are new processes. You would need to instead do exec("su -c 'command'")
- Running "mount -o rw...." should not be necessary because you are only reading from this partition, not writing to it.

I'd be interested to see if anyone has solved this one. Copying the file with ES File Explorer (with root access) works without a problem. I can also copy the file using a root ADB shell from the PC over USB. My app also has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in the Manifest.xml.